# How to get checkbox/radio being checked with given dynamic id in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to have something like this at 2 hard-code lines with `checked` that I comment: `checked = {searchParams.get('sort') === elementId}`. Are there any ways that I can achieve this?

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const SearchParams = () => {
  // searchParams.get('sort') will return "desc"/"asc" if there is "?sort=desc" or "?sort=asc" in the url
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, id } = event.target;
    setSearchParams({ [name]: id });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="sort"
        id="asc"
        onChange={handleChange}
        checked={searchParams.get('sort') === 'asc'} // hard code at this line...
      />
      <label htmlFor="asc">Ascending</label>
      <br />

      <input
        type="radio"
        name="sort"
        id="desc"
        onChange={handleChange}
        checked={searchParams.get('sort') === 'desc'} // ... and this line too
      />
      <label htmlFor="desc">Descending</label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchParams;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the element attributes are not accessible until the component has been fully rendered, however if you use a `map` and iterate over the ids, it will work.
Something like:

```js
const SearchParams = () => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const sortOrder = searchParams.get('sort');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, id } = event.target;
    setSearchParams({ [name]: id });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {['ascending', 'descending'].map((val, index) => (
        <Fragment key={val}>
            <input
                type="radio"
                name="sort"
                id={val}
                onChange={handleChange}
                checked={sortOrder === val}
            />
            <label htmlFor={id}>{id}</label>
            {index === 1 ? null : <br />}
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchParams;
```

Comment: This is the first time I see this kind of `ref`. Any fast explanation for this?

Comment: sorry, accidentally left that in, I was going to try a different approach using refs

Comment: Shaking my head for a while for this, but it has solved my problem anyway. Thank you